# I want Babel to transpile JSX but not async/await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs

I am following the instructions in this React Doc.

https://reactjs.org/docs/add-react-to-a-website.html#run-jsx-preprocessor

I have installed the dependencies as instructed:

```
npm install babel-cli@6 babel-preset-react-app@3
```

And to watch / transpile my source I use:

```
npx babel --watch src --out-dir dist --presets react-app/prod
```

This works great BUT, it not only transpiles JSX but also aysnc/await. Which all browsers I support (December 2020) already support async/await and therefore I would like to not transpile it. Is there another preset I should be using that would transpile JSX but not Async/Await?

Answer (score 1):

What's causing `async/await` to be transformed is `plugin-transform-regenerator`.

You can enable/disable it in [this REPL](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?browsers=defaults%2C%20not%20ie%2011%2C%20not%20ie_mob%2011&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAlgWwIIQJ5mDAvDAhmjACgEpsA-GAbwCgBIXAd1zlgAUAnEBOCAUwDp2vCCAA2AN16EA5AAk4AQmnFqAXyA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=env&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.12.11&externalPlugins=%40babel%2Fplugin-transform-regenerator%407.12.1) to demonstrate its effects. On the sidebar, scroll all the way down to plugins and click the `x` next to `plugin-transform-regenerator`.

You'd have to remove that preset and manually add all of the plugins and presets inherited from that preset to a babel config. I'm afraid it isn't possible to disable a specific plugin from a preset at the moment, as far as I know.

You can find all of the plugins and presets that preset is using here, under dependencies:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/packages/babel-preset-react-app/package.json

Here's documentation on putting together a babel config: https://babeljs.io/docs/en/configuration

Comment: I realize now it sounded like I was asking for a way to use a preset minus 1 plugin. But what I was actually looking for was if someone has already created a preset that includes all the plugins, but without `plugin-transform-regenerator`. The answer might be 'no' in which case I should probably make one.

Comment: There's likely some caveats that you'll have to field, but if you're relying 100% on a user having a modern browser, your only real requirement would be `@babel/preset-react`, since JSX is likely the only transformation needed short of any additional proposals you might be interested in using (i.e. optional chaining). That should make it a bit easier to reason about.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're able to achieve your role by using 2 common `babel` presets: `@babel/preset-env` & `@babel/preset-react` with latest version.

The key thing you might need to change to keep `async/await (a2)` is the `target` option of `preset-env`. As long as you set a browser to support `(a2)` such as `chrome: 80`, `babel` would keep them for you. Of course `@babel/preset-react` is all about for transform `jsx`.

Here's a step you need to do:

- Install deps:

```sh
npm i -D @babel/core @babel/cli @babel/preset-env @babel/preset-react
```

- Create a `babel.config.js`:

```js
const presets = [
  [
    "@babel/preset-env",
    {
      "targets": {
        "chrome": 80, // this version to support `async/await`
      },
      // "modules": false, // you might want it to native support esm in browser
    }
  ],
  "@babel/preset-react"
];


module.exports = { presets };
```

- Finally, run your test code:

```sh
npx babel --watch src --out-dir dist
```

NOTE: No need to specify presets here since it's configured via the file